# Custom airflow operator as "plugin" or direct import from dags directory

Tags: airflow

I wrote a custom operator (called `MyOperator`) which I would like to use to instantiate tasks in multiple DAGs. To achieve this, I put the package in `airflow/dags/operators` and perform a relative import in each dag definition file.

However, the official airflow documentation recommends using [their plugin interface](https://airflow.apache.org/plugins.html), which allows the operator to be imported from `airflow.operators.my_operator` rather than using a relative import.

Is the avoidance of relative imports the only advantage of using airflow plugins? **Is there any other reason I should be using the "official" approach?**

Since airflow plugins are loaded when the scheduler starts, it requires restarting the scheduler to reflect any changes made to `MyOperator`. If there are no clear advantages to using the official plugin interface, I will stick with relative imports.